# Google Maps by default

Tags: 8.1, maps, cortana

Is it possible to set Google maps as default map application so Cortana would use it instead of Bing? In my country Bing maps isn't working well that's why I want to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download a Map app with possibility to be chosen (don't know what is necessary).

After that follow this steps:

1. Go to Settings
2. Swipe right to applications
3. Go to maps
4. Choose the map experience you want to start in "set default voice navigation app"

   [image]

I recommend gMaps Pro as a Google Maps solution but I think Waze uses the same maps.