# How to map a contact's address using HERE Maps?

Tags: maps, here

When I view a contact and tap on "map home address", by default it opens the built-in Bing Maps app. However, I've found that it's not always able to correctly decipher the address (apartment numbers in particular seem to throw it off). Nokia's HERE Maps, on the other hand, have no such issues, so I'd like to use that for mapping contacts' addresses. Copy-pasting the address into HERE Maps each time is pretty cumbersome, so is there any way I can make the "map address" link in contacts open HERE Maps by default?

I've read the question [Google Maps by default](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3683), but judging by the accepted answer it only pertains to voice navigation, plus I've already set the default navigation app to HERE Drive+, but it has no effect in my use case.

I'm running Windows Phone 8.1 on a Lumia 920, in case it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Its possible to [change the default navigation app](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-set-default-navigation-app-windows-phone-81) in the settings, but not the default maps app. I hope this will change soon...

Comment: I hope so too. This is already possible on Windows 8.1, so hopefully Windows Phone will follow suit.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for your question, I found [this article](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-set-default-navigation-app-windows-phone-81) that shows how to set default navigation app for Windows Phone 8.1

However, scrolling through the comments by some users, I came across this comment

> Same here on my 920 in Australia, where no Cortana available. Clicking on contact address opens Bing maps even if I change default to HERE+ or Waze.
>   Perhaps this feature is broken if no Cortana available?

Sadly, it seems like taking Bing Maps as default even when HERE Drive+ is the default app for navigation purpose.

Comment: That's because the navigation app handler is completely different from the map app handler...

Comment: For what it's worth, enabling Cortana doesn't seem to make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: For me Cortana opens HERE Drive+ when I want to get directions. But I wish there was a feature where I can say "Cortana, get me directions to the Contacts Home Address."